# Python Requests Post - Additional field is not recognized for file upload

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have to post a file using Multipart upload to a company-internal REST service. The endpoint needs the file as property "file" and it needs an additional property "DestinationPath". Here is what I do:

```
url = r"http://<Internal IP>/upload"

files = {
  "DestinationPath": "/some/where/foo.txt",
  "file": open("test.txt", "rb")
}

response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

The server complains that it can't get the "DestinationPath". Full error message I receive is:

```
{'errors': {'DestinationPath': ['The DestinationPath field is required.']},
 'status': 400,
 'title': 'One or more validation errors occurred.',
 'traceId': '00-1993fbc53ab2ee418b683915dd7a440a-2338bd9cf34d414a-00',
 'type': 'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1'}
```

The file upload works in curl, thus it must be python specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @etemple1 I found the solution to my question:

```
url = r"http://<Internal IP>/upload"
data = {
    "DestinationPath": "/some/where/foo.txt",
}

with open("test.txt", "rb") as content:
    files = {
        "file": content.read(),
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

The data for the multipart upload needed to be divided between "data" and "files". They are later combined in the body of the http post by the requests library.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the `data` argument instead of `files`.

`response = requests.post(url, data=files)`

Comment: That results in the http error 415 for me. Is the binary data a problem for the data argument?

Comment: @wiemar that's possible. 415 means unsupported media type, so you probably want to include a headers dict and param in your request. You could also try passing the file binary in the `files` parameter. [Here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) is the interface for reference.

Comment: Thank you! The link was very helpful. I realized, that i have to split the my data into the 'files' and 'data' argument. Now it works!